# materialize css extended navbar overlaps with following content

Tags: html, css, materialize

According to [Materialize doc](https://materializecss.com/navbar.html), we could create an **extended navbar**, but I found that the extended nav could overlap with the following content (e.g. `div`).

Please see code example in [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/avocado123321/ovuydgm9/18/).

[image]

I thought maybe setting a `padding-top` on `body` could mitigate this issue, but I couldn't figure out how to get how much padding to use to resolve the overlapping issue.
Or is there any other better solutions?

Comment: @Manjuboyz, yes I need a fixed navbar, which could keep the navbar visible even if I scroll down the page.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [Materialize - "Fixed Nav"](https://materializecss.com/navbar.html#navbar-fixed) part :

"`navbar-fixed` will offset your other content while making your nav fixed."

So to resolve the problem you can remove `div` with `navbar-fixed` class.
Then to fix the navbar you can use `position: fixed` in css. Also use `position: relative` and `top` for content's division to make a distance from top of page.

I updated your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0bj7s1nd/7/) to resolve the issue.